# Typescript `typeof React.Component` does not extend interface? Trouble defining higher-order component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, higher-order-components

I'm creating a higher-order component to wrap a component extending the interface:

```
interface ClickOutsideInterface {
  onClickOutside: (e: Event) => void
}
```

The factory I've created expects a `React.ComponentClass` implementing the `ClickOutsideInterface`:

```
  function clickOutside<P>(Component: React.ComponentClass<P> & ClickOutsideInterface){    
    return class ClickOutside extends React.Component<P, {}> { 
      /* on click outside invoke Component.onClickOutside  */

      render() {
        return(<div><Component {...this.props} /></div>)
      }
   }
}
```

To test the factory, I've implement a Component extending the `ClickOutsideInterface`

```
class Test extends React.Component<TProps, TState> implements ClickOutsideInterface {
  onClickOutside(event: Event): void {
    this.setState({
      closed: true
    })
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>{this.state.closed}</div>
    )
  }
}
```

But when I use the component as an argument in the function `clickOutside`:

```
const withClickOutside = clickOutside(Test)
```

I get the following type error for argument `Test`:

> Argument of type 'typeof Test' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'ComponentClass & ClickOutsideInterface'.   Type 'typeof Test' is
>   not assignable to type 'ClickOutsideInterface'.
>       Property 'onClickOutside' is missing in type 'typeof Test'.

Any ideas why Typescript believes I'm not implementing the interface in `Test`?

Comment: Its not about decorator? `withClickOutside()(Test)`

Comment: probably yes :)

Comment: @DmitriyKovalenko decorator or not, if this function were a decorator your suggested invocation would be incorrect because it is a decorator factory invocation not a decorator invocation. It would only be valid if `clickOutside` returned a function which could be used as a decorator. That wouldn't make sense here anyway because it wouldn't take any arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TypeScript says that you haven't implemented the interface your function requires of its argument because you indeed have not.

When you write

```
class A {
  //...
}
```

You define two types and one value.

The *value*, which is named `A`, is the class. It is the function that you call with `new` to create objects.

The first *type*, which is also named `A`, is the type of the objects that are *created* by calling the class function with `new` as described above.

The second *type* is the type of that class function. Declaring a class doesn't automatically create a name for this type but the type exists none the less because all values have a type. This type is written `typeof A` because it is the type of the value `A`, the type of the class.

Therefore, depending on what you're trying to accomplish, you need to either

Pass an instance of `Test`

```
const withClickOutside = clickOutside(new Test);
```

Or change your function so that it takes an object matching the type of the class itself, and not the objects it creates

```
function clickOutside<P>(
  Component: new () => React.ComponentClass<P> & ClickOutsideInterface
) {...}
```

I suspect it is the latter that you want in this case.

Lastly, while you may want it for documentation purposes which is a completely valid, I'd like to note that there's no reason to actually declare that your class even implements the interface at all. TypeScript is a structurally typed language and all interfaces are implemented by having compatible members.

Comment: thanks Aluan! I was able to get it working by using, as you recommended, ` Component: new(props: P) => React.Component<P> & ClickOutsideInterface` Thanks! I'd like to be able to reference `React.ComponentClass` `displayName` or the methods exposed on `ClickOustideInterface` like `Component.onClickOutside` within the HO Component -- is there a way to access the return type of the function `Component` ?  somethign like `Component: new(props: P) => (C: React.Component<P> & ClickOutsideInterface)`

Comment: @tgk are those static members of the class?

Comment: you can make it take any constrictor arguments that you like using the syntax that you mentioned

Comment: no unfortunately they are not static members of the class -- I somehow need to restructure my factory to have access to the instance.