# Typescript generics: Refer to class instead of instance

Tags: typescript, generics

I've got a situation where I want to use a generic type in a set of interfaces. My public interface receives the generic type and passes it down to the non-exported private interfaces. In my public interface I want to use the generic type `T`, but I **don't** want it to refer to an *instance* of `T`. I want it to say that it is `T`, the class, that can produce instances of `T`.

Trying this, I get an error:

```js
interface Car<T> {
  unit: T;
  progress: number;
}

export interface CarFactory<T> {
  cars: Car<T>[];
  // Type error: 'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.  TS2693
  blueprint: typeof T;
}
```

Using a generator function works. But then I have to pass that down and expose more of the internals of my code, which I want to avoid.

```js
interface CarFactory<T> {
  blueprint: (args: any) => T;
}
```

I can't use `T` directly, as that causes the compiler to think it should receive an instance of `T`, not the class. This triggers a `TS2740` error. Using `T = CarModel` and `T['constructor']` as the `blueprint` type works, but only if I patch my class like this:

```js
class CarModel {
  public ['constructor']: typeof CarModel;
}
```

So the question is: How can I use generics like this? Using both instances of `T` and the actual `T`? Are a generator function or `['constructor']` with a patched `T` my only alternatives? Would I need to pass down another generic type `U` that is something along the lines of `U = typeof T`?

Comment: What is `T` supposed to be in `Car<T>`? It's some sort of Car that only works with a given type but I'm not sure if that's what you mean here. Perhaps you don't even need a generic for Car. It seems more logical to me to have `interface Car` without a generic and then something like `interface CarFactory<T extends Car>` because the CarFactory will create something that is a Car.

Comment: There is no direct link between the instance type and the class type if that is wht you are after. There is a proposal to type `constructor` as you have in `CarModel` automatically, but it is not yet implemented

Comment: I realized I got confused in converting my code to a example here. Fixed my question to be more to the point. Sorry for being unclear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

Given a class `Car` the [type of the class itself](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#constructor-functions) (the symbol `Car` that references the class' constructor function) would be `typeof Car`. In `CarFactory` interface, we do not have some concrete class, so we can use the [type of the constructor function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47002610/5669456) `new (...args: any) => T` for `blueprint`:

```
export interface CarFactory<T> {
  cars: Car<T>[];
  // use a constructor function type here
  blueprint: new (...args: any) => T;
}
```

Test it:

```
class CombiUnit {
  // your implementation of a car unit/model T goes here
}

type CombiUnitFactory = CarFactory<CombiUnit>;

// new (...args: any) => CombiUnit
type CombiUnitFactoryCtorFunction = CombiUnitFactory["blueprint"];

// some concrete factory
declare const t1: CombiUnitFactory;

const result = new t1.blueprint(); // const result: CombiUnit
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJygHgCoD5kDeAUMsgK4jBgBcy2A3CcgA5QD2A5lBAM4+0gyAWwBG0RgF8iRCAA9mbKGGShIsRCnRQAYojCKAnjnzFSCDPzQZjAbQC6jUgHondA8xTR2UWgHJsvshsIAA2BsjcMNA8yPrIcLHuEAA0yCJkysAxYqAc5DwQACbxMQkAbnAhZCgAFtAQAHSk2ADKAEwAbACcAMxMIlUQrKoCEADuyAAUDTMYHJZwIAYAlMgAvPgMRFJECCFwfGhsosAAqpTKpsguyAZsZFAqQswhEEIQ4HBgwMFBMPHIcyPIRsQoQEJpQbDcDIDhsXjIOrcbbSMBJI4nc5UXQIfRQcJrKw6PSGTCoY4iM4XXCMIg3EDjKYzBpzBZLVYbDGUrFgIhojxcqnYkn41B47QUXE-EDrQU8nF4gw2ABEA2q0LAyoc0huPGOKAQwQQ3EgyHguMMRDBewwBuCPGUYAAjLRyZiLgrDLTDSAHRFeGQQspCQyJs6GmqhlBVJNlvRrq4fX7uDxAzQ5RciEA)

Comment: Yes! Exactly like that. `new (...args: any) => T` was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The *typeof* operator effectively returns a value. It's sufficient to write

```
interface Car<T> {
  blueprint: T;
}
```

Besides that, I think that a factory class should be static, therefore doesn't require an interface. You could instead make a static car factory class like this:

```
export class AutomobileFactory {
  static createCar<T>(): Car<T> {
    // create a concrete car implementation of the
    // generic type T instead of throwing an error
    throw new Error("Not implemented");
  }
}
```

Comment: I updated my examples and question to be less confusing and explain the situation more direct. Thank you for your answer though!

Also, to avoid creating static methods with run-time errors, you can use [abstract classes and methods](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#abstract-classes).